# Based on the ACF and PACF, identify the most appropriate ARIMA(p,d,q) model for the residuals and and explain your reasoning

Tags: acf-pacf

[image]

The number of significant terms in ACF = 17
The number of significant terms in PACF = 8

We are going to use AR in this model since PACF is less than ACF. AR is 8 and MA is 17. Since we only took the first difference for the trend, then d is 1. P is the number of significant terms in PACF for trend. Q is the number of significant terms in ACF for trend. So, ARIMA(8,1,17) is the most appropriate model for the residuals.

Would this be a correct interpretation?